# Updating a Temp Table through another Temp Table using PySpark and Databricks environment

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to use a streaming base which is continuously updated (every 2min) in a indirectly way.

To summarize the issue: this streaming base is something like:

```
%sql
create or replace temporary view TEMP1 as
select 1+1 as sum
```

So, I can call it in pyspark in this way:

```
%python
df = sqlContext.sql('''
select *
from df''')
```

Finally I would like to call df in another cell:

```
%python
df.show() #data must be updated without the needed to run df = sqlContext again while TEMP1 will be continously updated
```

Any Idea How should I solve this? And, yes, I'm new in pyspark :(

Answer (score 0):

I found way to do this: transforming df into a function!:

```
def df():
  return sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM TEMP1")
```

So I could call it:

```
df().show()
```

It is not "elegant" however it does the job